Fetching from Kafka sessionStore is very slow (5-10 seconds) why?
I am currently doing a uni project for stream processing and am currently stuck trying to implement a session store, because it takes multiple seconds to do a fetch operation on a store that does not have many keys.
We are streaming some mock factory data, which has some light sensors that are either broken or not. So my idea was to filter out the events, where the light has not been broken, and then do a SessionWindow to see for how long each light sensor is broken at a time.
To achieve the stream where only events with broken light sensors come through i did this:
        KStream<String, HbwEvent> lightBarrierBrokenHBW = hbwTypedStream.filterNot((k, v) ->
                v.getData().isI1_light_barrier() && v.getData().isI4_light_barrier());

Then i grouped the stream based on which light barrier was broken:
        SessionWindowedKStream<String, HbwEvent> sessionizedHbwEvent = lightBarrierBrokenHBW
                .groupBy((k, v) -> {
                    String sensorKey = "unknown";
                    if (!v.getData().isI4_light_barrier()) {
                        sensorKey = "i4_light_sensor";
                    } else if (!v.getData().isI1_light_barrier()) {
                        sensorKey = "i1_light_sensor";
                    }
                    System.out.println("GroupBy: " + k + " -> " + sensorKey);
                    return sensorKey;
                }, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), hbwEventSerdes))
                .windowedBy(sessionWindow);

I then did the aggregation and materialized it to a store:
        sessionizedHbwEvent.aggregate(
                TimeDifferenceAggregation::new,
                TimeDifferenceAggregation::add,
                TimeDifferenceAggregation::merge,
                Materialized.<String, TimeDifferenceAggregation, SessionStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("lightSensor")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(timeDifferenceAggregationSerde)
                        .withCachingEnabled()
        );

The TimeDifferenceAggregation class looks like this:
@Setter
@Getter
public class TimeDifferenceAggregation {
    @SerializedName("FirstTimestamp")
    private Instant firstTimestamp;
    @SerializedName("LastTimestamp")
    private Instant lastTimestamp;

    public TimeDifferenceAggregation() {
        this.firstTimestamp = null;
        this.lastTimestamp = null;
    }

    public TimeDifferenceAggregation(Instant firstTimestamp, Instant lastTimestamp) {
        this.firstTimestamp = firstTimestamp;
        this.lastTimestamp = lastTimestamp;
    }

    public static TimeDifferenceAggregation add(String Key, HbwEvent event, TimeDifferenceAggregation agg) {
        Instant newTime = Instant.parse(event.getTime());

        Instant newFirstTimestamp = (agg.firstTimestamp == null || newTime.isBefore(agg.firstTimestamp)) ? newTime : agg.firstTimestamp;
        Instant newLastTimestamp = (agg.lastTimestamp == null || newTime.isAfter(agg.lastTimestamp)) ? newTime : agg.lastTimestamp;

        return new TimeDifferenceAggregation(newFirstTimestamp, newLastTimestamp);
    }

    public static TimeDifferenceAggregation merge(String Key, TimeDifferenceAggregation agg1, TimeDifferenceAggregation agg2) {
        Instant newFirstTimestamp;
        Instant newLastTimestamp;

        if (agg1.firstTimestamp != null && agg2.firstTimestamp != null) {
            newFirstTimestamp = agg1.firstTimestamp.isBefore(agg2.firstTimestamp) ? agg1.firstTimestamp : agg2.firstTimestamp;
        } else if (agg1.firstTimestamp != null) {
            newFirstTimestamp = agg1.firstTimestamp;
        } else {
            newFirstTimestamp = agg2.firstTimestamp;
        }

        if (agg1.lastTimestamp != null && agg2.lastTimestamp != null) {
            newLastTimestamp = agg1.lastTimestamp.isAfter(agg2.lastTimestamp) ? agg1.lastTimestamp : agg2.lastTimestamp;
        } else if (agg1.lastTimestamp != null) {
            newLastTimestamp = agg1.lastTimestamp;
        } else {
            newLastTimestamp = agg2.lastTimestamp;
        }

        return new TimeDifferenceAggregation(newFirstTimestamp, newLastTimestamp);
    }

Technically the program works as it should, but it is very very slow. So if anyone has encountered a similar problem or has some pointers that would be appreciated! The KafkaStreams are started through a @Configuration bean, with barebones configurations. The Store is exposed through a Bean like this:
    @Bean
    public ReadOnlySessionStore<String, TimeDifferenceAggregation> lightSensorStore(KafkaStreams streams) {
        return streams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType("lightSensor", QueryableStoreTypes.sessionStore()));
    }

In the same application I am doing a normal KeyValueStore for some other aggregation, and this has the normal speed of only some ms. So I am really unsure what i did wrong with the SessionWindow based one?
Thank you!
I have tried multiple additional StreamsConfig settings, such as more threads, expanding cache, etc. All with no real improvement. I logged all operations and am 100% sure the culprit is the .fetch("i4_light_sensor") operation. I have also queried the endpoint multiple times, in case the first read was just slow, but it did not really improve even after multiple queries.
This is the endpoint that im testing it with atm:
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTest() {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonitoringRestController.class);

        long fetchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var range = lightSensorStore.fetch("i4_light_sensor");
        long fetchEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        logger.info("Fetch and process time: {} ms", (fetchEndTime - fetchStartTime));
        
        while(range.hasNext()) {
            var next = range.next();
            System.out.println(next.key.key());
            System.out.println(next.value.getFirstTimestamp());
            System.out.println(next.value.getLastTimestamp());
        }
        range.close();
        return "successs";
    }

EDIT: I have done some additional testing and found some interesting behaviour. I switched from fetch() to backwardsFetch() and immeadiately the backwardsFetch() operation was a couple ms. The iteration through the sessions was also as fast as expected, but somehow it got stuck at the end? -> What i mean is once it printed both sessions It just did something and then finished:
    public String getTest() {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonitoringRestController.class);

        long fetchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        KeyValueIterator<Windowed<String>, TimeDifferenceAggregation> range = lightSensorStore.backwardFetch("i4_light_sensor");
        long fetchEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        logger.info("Fetch and process time: {} ms", (fetchEndTime - fetchStartTime)); // Fetch and process time: 1 ms

        long processStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        range.forEachRemaining(n ->
                logger.info("Key: {}, First Timestamp: {}, Last Timestamp: {}", n.key.key(), n.value.getFirstTimestamp(), n.value.getLastTimestamp())); // both expected sessions got logged instantely

        range.close();

        long processEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Processing time: 9438 ms
        logger.info("Processing time: {} ms", (processEndTime - processStartTime));

        long responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Total response time: {} ms", (responseTime - fetchStartTime)); // Total response time: 9440 ms

        return "success";
    }

So my thought is, that something at the end of the iterator makes it slow? Is there some special logic that i am unaware of, when it comes to iterating over a KeyValueIterator like this?
